# first item in ng-option becomes blank on its own

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

the 1st (FIRST!!) item in a combo box simply goes blank.

the item is actually there, but gets invisible. **it only gets visible when I click on it**. when I click on any other item, the 1st item disappears (becomes blank) again.

the problem only happens to the 1st item in the combo box.

this is not the default initial blank item that is commonly seen in many combo box. it is a real item, with a real value, that becomes blank out of nothing inside the combo.

I'm not applying any sort of filter on the ng-options.

could someone help?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I came across same problem before. You can use $scope.form = {type : $scope.yourOptions[0].value};

Comment: I'll post the code tomorrow because I'm not at the office anymore. $scope.form = {type : $scope.yourOptions[0].value}; doesn't seem to apply to my case. I don't want to hide the normal blank item at the beginning of the list. I want to make a real item - that is in the 1st position of the list and that is invisible - to become visible. It only gets visible if I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-init="v1.... = 'A'"` or `ng-init="v1.... = 'D'"`  with your ng-model like following. thanks to ng-init, we can set initial option in select element.

```
<select ng-init="v1.... = 'D'"
        data-ng-disabled="v1.array2.length == 0 || v1.butt != '2'" 
        class="col7" 
        name="orderOptions" 
        id="orderOptId" 
        data-ng-click="v1....()" 
        data-ng-model="v1...." >
        <option value="A">Ascending</option>
        <option value="D">Descending</option>
</select>
```

Comment: as far as I can see it doesn't apply to my case. please see my comment above. I'll post my code tomorrow because I'm not at my office right now. thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2568276 ok then i can take a look at your code tomorrow :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the interest. please, see my answer bellow.

Comment: @user2568276 I am gonna edit my answer in ten minutes

Comment: @user2568276 I have updated, I am waiting your feedback :)

Comment: I was wondering if I could simply declare the options inside the html only (see my html below). I mean, I don't have the $scope.typeOptions in the  javascript. How should I use it in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @user2568276 I have updated my answer, you can use ng-init in your html

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to make the 1st item visible inside the combo-box. I tried many options and the one that worked was removing the

```
<div class='modal-body'> </div>
```

from the modal html and replacing it for

```
<form class='form'> </form>.
```

the main body of the modal is now inside the "form". I wonder why it worked.

I also have a question about the

```
$scope.form = {type : $scope.typeOptions[0].value};
```

thing. I want to use it in another situation, but the list is declare in the html, not in the javascript. I mean, there is no "$scope.typeOptions" or equivalent in my javascript. I have the following in my html

```
                <div >
                 <select data-ng-disabled="v1.array2.length == 0 || v1.butt != '2'" 
                        class="col7" 
                        name="orderOptions" 
                        id="orderOptId" 
                        data-ng-click="v1....()" 
                        data-ng-model="v1...." >
                        <option value="A">Ascending</option>
                        <option value="D">Descending</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

In this case, how should I use it?

Thanks.